# Android Service making socket connection hangs in readline()

Tags: android, sockets, service

I am facing an issue with an Android service which makes a socket connection with the server, after the connection is setup, sometimes (not always) the thread hangs in readline function, even though the server is successfully sending the data appending new line character to every message, the android service does not read anything getting stuck in the readline() only.

I have tried  simple read() to read character by character but it also hangs in there.

```
public class TCPService extends Service {
Socket socket;
PrintStream os;
String message;
private Messenger messageHandler;

private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

public TCPService() {
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public TCPService getService() {
    System.out.println("I am in Localbinder ");
    Log.d("abc","I am in Localbinder ");
    return TCPService.this;

    }
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
System.out.println("I am in Ibinder onBind method");
Log.d("abc","I am in Ibinder onBind method");
    // return myBinder;
return null;
}

public void IsBoundable(){
    Toast.makeText(this,"I bind like butter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d("abc","Service Started");
    Log.d("abc", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started TCPService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Runnable connect = new connectSocket();
    new Thread(connect).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}



class connectSocket implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean running = true;

        //while (running)

            try {
                String msg;          
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("X.X.X.X");
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, 4444));
                Log.d("abc", "socket variable is " + socket);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "US-ASCII"));
               BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new  OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "US-ASCII"));
                out.write("clientapp");
                out.write("\n");
                out.flush();
                while (true) {
                try {
                        msg = in.readLine();
                        Log.d("abc", "msg =" + msg);
                        if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
                            break;
                        } else if (msg.length() != 0) {
                            message = msg;
                            Log.d("abc", "you got reply ---" + message);
                            sendBroadcast();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("abc", "nothing read from server, msg = " + msg);
                            break;
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("abc", "IOException by readLine " + e1.getMessage());
                        break;
                    }

                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("abc", "UnknownHostException " + e1.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("abc", "IOException " + e1.getMessage());


            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
 }
```

}
}

Please help me in debugging it. I have put several print statements and breakpoints but nothing worked.

Comment: I'd say the null-check is missing. This is how I read the stream: `String line = null; while( null != ( line = reader.readLine() ) ){ doStuff() }`

Comment: omg what a variety of "debug tools" 1) System.out.println 2) Log.d 3) Toast.makeText; use one, #2 namely